# How to make express application container connect to mongodb container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-network

I created an express application configured  with Mongodb for database that connect locally on my machine. I have decided to Dockerize this application and run the image as container but there seems to be a problem, my container connecting to a database on local port 27017. I figured out that my container cannot connect to any host services so I pulled mongo image from docker hub and started it, but before, I created  network and started both containers with --network=mynetwork flag but still the express app container returns mongodb connection error.

Someone help

Comment: Can you share the commands used to run the container, in addition the connection string used by the express application?

Comment: command to start the mongo image after creating the network sudo docker run -d --network=mynetwork --name mongodb  mongo.   Command to run the express image sudo docker run -d --network=mynetwork --name backend yolobackend:1.0.0. And my string connection is 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017' in server.js

Comment: 127.0.0.1 in Docker almost always means "the current container", not another container or the host system.  Consider searching SO for similar problems: this is a frequent and general Docker problem, and you should be able to configure Docker and fix the host name even based on questions for other databases and languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Express is trying to connect MongoDB on the host
`127.0.0.1` which refers to the same container. You have several options to solve this, two of them are

#### Change the network to `host`

This will make the containers run on the same network interface as the host, so all the ports are exposed then when the express requests `127.0.0.1` it'll reach MongoDB.

```bash
sudo docker run -d --network=host --name mongodb mongo
sudo docker run -d --network=host --name backend yolobackend:1.0.0
```

#### Use docker network DNS service

Because both of containers are running in the same network (mynetwork) they can communicate. Docker provides a DNS service the resolves the container's IP based on the container name only if they are in the same network and it is explicitly provided (not the default network), so changing the connection string to

```bash
mongodb://mongodb:27017
```

where the host is your MongoDB container name.
Redeploy your application will solve your problem.

I recommend you checking out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKFMS5C4CG0).